How catch and mute "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call" error
I'm opening a pop-up from a page (main page). I'm then checking constantly if the pop-up is still open or has been closed. I'm doing that with the code below
const checkForPopUp = async function() {
    try {
        while(!extFrame?.closed) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 250));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

However, at some point the pop-up redirects to another domain so the browser throws the error Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call directly when checking if the pop-up is still open or not. The error is not caught by try/catch nor by window.onerror, nor by window.onunhandledrejection.
How can I catch this specific error and handle it differently so that it doesn't print as an error?

I am pretty sure you won't be able to fix this since the link between the two windows gets severed by redirecting, the browser will from then (correctly) assume that it is a cross-origin window, and it will not reconnect it either.

That's fine, I just want to read and handle that error/exception with code properly. Right now I only see the error in the console but I haven't been able to find a way to access that particular error as it's possible with other errors

Might it be that the window will never be marked as close since it won't be updated any longer and wasn't actually closed when it was connected? If you own this domain you could perhaps do this with a shared session between tabs (I forget what the API is called but it can be used to keep states and windows on the same domain in sync)

The use-case is cross-domain only. Even if the pop-up never closes, we should have the ability to catch the error with code and not only in the console

It depends whether the error occurred on your page, or on the page that is being forwarded - it is likely that error you are seeing before it forwards? It makes sense to cut of the link when CORS becomes and issue to prevent leaking anything from another domain. It would suggest going through iframes instead and not browser popup windows.

The error is triggered/printed in the window that opened the pop-up (the opener), not in the console of the pop-up itself that moves to another domain. When I open an iFrame, and that iFrame later navigates to another domain, I can catch with code when I don't have access to the current iFrame page anymore but with this Pop-up error we are blind. Every error should be catchable with code, at least to know there is an error

Shouldn't your try/catch then wrap the open function instead of the .closed check? Try wrapping you entire code and see if you can catch it.
